# Playing copy-protected video content in Java (e.g. via HDCP)

Tags: java, video, drm, copy-protection, hdcp

Is it possible to play a video stream from Java in such a way that it cannot be captured during playback (preferably not even single screenshots)? Would HDCP allow for such a restriction? If so, is HDCP somehow accessible via Java?

Comment: Wouldn't be very copy-protected if you could, now, would it? ;) There are [articles](http://adamsblog.aperturelabs.com/2013/02/hdcp-is-dead-long-live-hdcp-peek-into.html) on the subject, but not sure of the skill level required or the legality of things.

Comment: @Qix: No no! :) I'm not trying to hack HDCP and play protected content which I'm not supposed to. I have content, which I own and I want to protect. I would like to have a way to play a video through Java in such a way that nobody else can capture this video. I want to **protect** the video, not break existing protection... Sorry for being unclear... :)

Answer (score 0):

HDCP is not what you are looking for. Even if it is what you are looking for, you need to buy the HDCP keys from DCP (tons of formalities and money) and make sure that you keep them very safe. Even if you do this, anybody could play your video when they hook an HDCP enabled display.

Comment: I definitely want people to be able to play my video if they hook into an HDCP display. All I want to prevent is for them to capture frames or video sequences from it. Don't most operating systems or video card drivers already have the HDCP keys built in? Windows DRM, for example, already has the ability to play protected video in a way that it can't be captured (via HDCP, I assume). Is it possible to just tap into those APIs? Software like PowerDVD and such must use it, I would think. I just don't know whether these APIs are accessible from Java...